# phplist on Ubuntu 16.04.1 server - Initialize the Database no reaction

Tags: php, ubuntu-server, phplist

I got a new server with Ubuntu 16.04.1 installed. It comes with php7
I installed phplist-3.2.5 in the root of the host pr.xxx.com

I tried in the config file:

```
$pageroot = '/';
```

and

```
$pageroot = '';
```

http://pr.example.com/admin let me fill out the PhpList initialisation, but the button [Continue] does not show me any reaction.

No log file (syslog, apache error) gives me a clue.

login to the mysql shows that the table has not been created either.

Maybe related: On the right side I get the information:
Error on line 66 of /var/www/pr.example.com/admin/ui/dressprow/onyx-rss.php: PHP's XML Extension is not loaded or available.

How can I track down this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
```